# PDO Prepared statements and password hashing?

Tags: php, pdo, hash

ive looked all over the internet to try to solve this problem and i cant find figure it out for the life of me. Really starting to give up.

So basically whenever i login with the correct email and correct password it says incorrect email or password. This only happens whenever i hash the password in the db

**Email**: test@gmail.com

**Password**: testtest

**Hash**: $2y$10$hk3d/GyYvImcxYR.vdC2/.JDIeQeXyKdTSPifueAkQNrYVBcMn1Yi

Anyways if someone could help me that would be amazing here is my **login.php** code.

````php
<?php
    require "../private/php/autoload.php";
    $error = "";
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_SESSION['token']) && isset($_POST['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(!preg_match("/^[\w\-]+@[\w\-]+.[\w\-]+$/", $email)){
            $error = "Please enter a valid email.";
        }
        
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        if ($error == ""){
            $arr['email'] = $email;
            $arr['password'] = $password;
            
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email && password = :password LIMIT 1";
            $stm = $conn->prepare($query);
            $check = $stm->execute($arr);
            
            if($check){
                $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                if(is_array($data) && count($data) > 0){
                    $data = $data[0];
                    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $data->password)){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $data->username;
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $data->user_id;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                    die;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $error = "Wrong email or password!";
    }
    $_SESSION['token'] = get_random_string(30);
?>```
````

Comment: Obviously in your database password is stored as hash and therefore `password = :password` is __never true__.

Comment: So my query is the issue? How do i fix that

Comment: Query by email only. And then compare hash using `password_verify`

Comment: @CharlesEF no, password_verify is the way it's designed and recommended to be used in PHP. You can read about it in the manual

Comment: @JohnnyOrlando to fix the query just remove `&& password = :password`, and remove `$arr['password'] = $password;`

Comment: @ADyson could you show me how to do it correctly please? ive been on this for 5 hours

Comment: Well I just showed you the most important steps. Try that first

Comment: As a totally separate aside, this bit `if(!preg_match("/^[\w\-]+@[\w\-]+.[\w\-]+$/", $email)){
            $error = "Please enter a valid email.";
        }` is completely redundant in the context of a login page. You only need that when they're first registering. At login time, if the user enters total gibberish as the username that's their problem not yours, you don't need to check it - it simply will not find a user account.

Comment: @Adyson I did that to keep some text vulnerabilities from happening. Is there anyway I can contact you? Such as discord

Comment: What text vulnerability, exactly? All that bit of code does is check whether the input text looks like an email address. But it it doesn't look like one, so what? It can't hurt your database because you're using prepared statements. So it just isn't needed.

Comment: Anyway I'm right here already if you want to talk about this code. Did you make the changes I suggested earlier to your query? They should stop it trying to match the plain password to the hashed version, and should mean you now get a row returned from the database which you can then run password_verify against

Answer (score 2):

Your MySQL table contains the password hashed, but you're querying it passing through the un-hashed password which is why it's not matching/working presently.

Also, worth noting that this could be bad from a security point of view as the plaintext password is being transmitted and could easily end up in your MySQL logs (Slow Log, Error if there was any issue etc.).

Swap the query out to just look up on the email address alone (assuming it's unique), and then verify the password hashes match in your PHP logic against the MySQL result.